# why .net-core react template is not typescript

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am new in react application development, I 've just created new application with Visual Studio 2017  Enterprise edition, everythings looks good, but the react part are all in javascript format (.js) not type type-script format (.jsx) , I read some tutorials but when they create a react application all are type script ! is there something else which I have to do ?
an example for these tutorials is : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51632.asp-net-core-2-0-crud-with-react-js-and-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: 1. The ASP.NET Core team has already changed the template in order to be as consistent as possible with the de-facto standards used by each SPA technology, See [discussion here](https://github.com/aspnet/Templating/issues/242#issuecomment-359865442) . 2. If you really want to use `TypeScript`,  update your dependency to use `"react-scripts": "^2.1.0",`, and install types by `npm i --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest @types/react-router`. And now you  can use the typescript as you like. You don't need to create the `tsconfig.json` or `webpack`

Comment: The answer to "why" is that Microsoft is afraid to stand by great tech it develops and promotes but instead has gotten caught up in the flavor-of-the-month thinking that plagues the rest of the industry. They're now a follower not a leader.